# Git Bash not showing up as a option in VS Code terminal - Custom Path

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

I've added Git.exe and Git Cmd [to my PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vvkt.png), I've seen tons of articles online and I don't know!

I want to add Git Bash to my VS Code terminal but it's not showing up as a option nor is it working through the settings.json. When I use git --version it works, so I have git installed and its added to my PATH. I do however have a custom file path.

I'm quite new to git so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but here is the code I added to my settings.json file:

```
  // Terminal
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Git Bash": { "path": "G:\\Coding Programs\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe" }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"
```

UPDATE, I just realized [this little message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sO0W.png) when I use "Git-Bash" or "Git Bash" as the "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows" option

Comment: Does it show up by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + ~`?

Comment: The terminal? Nope

Comment: Replace both `Git Bash` with `Git-Bash`. It seems a string with spaces cannot be recognized.

Comment: This isn't actually a Git issue, it's strictly VSCode. Note that git-bash is a port of bash provided *with* Git-for-Windows (but not provided with Git for other systems, i.e., not part of Git itself). VSCode is very configurable, sometimes too configurable it seems :-)

Comment: Besides, the space in the path string could be one of the causes. Paths of Windows, especially with spaces, are nightmares.

Comment: Elipekay, I do understand where you are coming from saying that spaces may be a nightmare. However, isn't the default path also in "Program Files"? So I think I may have another issue going on

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this via MarketPlace from within VSCode.
[image]

Once you will install it, you should see an option in the terminal window to open a git bash terminal within VSCode ( please refer to the attached screen shot ) :

[image]

I have been using this from months now and it works like charm!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response but unfortunately this didn't work for me

Comment: Can you please share the error or any other prompt which is telling the error details ?

Comment: I don't see any error, it just doesnt show up as a option

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and @ElpieKay's comment worked for me: problem was fixed after removing the space in the terminal's name. Mind the dash at 2 places in settings.json, see below. It sounds weird since another terminal named "Command Prompt" works without any problem.

Additional side note: I first tried to use `C:\Path\To\Git\git-bash.exe`, but this always create a new window (sometimes hidden behind other windows), and not a panel inside VsCode. To avoid this, use `C:\Path\To\Git\bin\bash.exe` (as correctly proposed by OP).

```
{
    // other settings...,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        // other terminals...,
        "Git-Bash": {
            "path": "C:\\Apps\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git-Bash"
}
```